# How to sort odd and even numbers of an array in a specific format

Tags: r

I have a vector like this

```
seq_vector <- c(3,12,5,9,11,8,4,6,7,11,15,3,9,10,12,2)
```

I want to format them in descending order of odd numbers, followed by ascending order of even numbers. Output of above seq_vector will be

```
new_seq_vector <- c(15,11,11,9,9,7,5,3,3,2,4,6,8,10,12,12)
```

Can you please help me with the logic of the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `x[order(x*v)]` where `v` is -1 for odd, +1 for even.

Thanks to @lmo for this:

```
x[order( x*(-1)^x )]
# [1] 15 11 11  9  9  7  5  3  3  2  4  6  8 10 12 12
```

So `v = (-1)^x` here.

---

Some other ways to build `v`: @d.b's `(-1)^(x %% 2)`; and mine, `1-2*(x %% 2)`.

(Thanks @d.b) If `x` contains negative integers, an additional sorting vector is needed:

```
# new example
x = c(2, 5, -15, -10, 1, -3, 12)
x[order(v <- (-1)^x, x*v)]
# [1]   5   1  -3 -15 -10   2  12
```

Comment: Also `seq_vector[order(seq_vector * (-1)^seq_vector)]`.

Comment: @lmo, that's clever

Comment: @d.b Thanks. These are fun puzzles.

Comment: I'd argue that it's good to see multiple methods. Alternatives may be easier to plug into a related problem.

Comment: I think `x[order(-(x%%2),x*(-1)^x)]` would also handle negative values

Comment: Thanks @d.b Does my edit work? If not, feel free to edit the question directly.

Answer (score 3):

Take modulus by 2 (`%% 2`) to determine the odd and even elements and `sort` accordingly.

```
c(sort(seq_vector[seq_vector %% 2 == 1], decreasing = TRUE),             #For odd
                               sort(seq_vector[seq_vector %% 2 == 0]))   #For even
 #[1] 15 11 11  9  9  7  5  3  3  2  4  6  8 10 12 12
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an auxiliary function.

```
is.odd <- function(x) (x %% 2) == 1

result <- c(sort(seq_vector[is.odd(seq_vector)], decreasing = TRUE),
            sort(seq_vector[!is.odd(seq_vector)]))
result
```

Comment: @d.b I was writing and testing my answer when you posted yours. So I only saw it after.